# Approximating a Distribution with an Ising Model/pairwise MRF

Tags: pr.probability, ising-model

I want to know if there are any results on approximating a distribution with an Ising model/pairwise Markov Random Fields (MRFs).

Formally, let $\mathcal{I}$ be the set of all Ising models/pairwise MRFs on $\{-1, 1\}^n$, that is $p \in \mathcal{I}$ if $\displaystyle p(x_1, \dots, x_n) \propto \exp\left(\sum_{v \in [n]} \theta_{v} x_v + \sum_{u, v \in [n] \times [n]} \theta_{u,v} x_u x_v\right)$ for some constants $\theta_v, \theta_{u,v}$.

Let $q$ be any distribution on $\{-1, 1\}^n$, and suppose $q \not\in \mathcal{I}$. Are there any papers that discuss bounds on $\inf_{p \in \mathcal{I}} d(p,q)$, for some distance $d$ (e.g. total variation or KL divergence)?

Specifically, I am wondering if $\inf_{p \in \mathcal{I}} d(p,q) = 0$ for all $q$, so that $\mathcal{I}$ is "dense" in the set of all probability distributions on $\{-1, 1\}^n$, or if $\inf_{p \in \mathcal{I}} d(p,q)$ is bounded away from $0$.

Thanks!